# Kernel and Image (of endomorphism) inclusions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Are these propositions always true (for any $u \in \mathscr{L}(E) \neq 0$) ?

- $\mathrm{Ker}(u) \subsetneq \mathrm{Ker}(u^2)$
- $\mathrm{Im}(u^2) \subsetneq \mathrm{Im}(u)$

If it is, how can I prove it ? The inclusions are obvious, but I can't figure out how to prove the non-equality ..

Thanks

Comment: What if $u={\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 1  \\  \end{pmatrix}}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both statements are not true. Just consider $u=\text{id}$, the identity map.